# Minecraft instantly disconnects when trying to get onto a LAN server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

Every time I try to connect on the same LAN, the Minecraft server says `Logging in` and instantly after this throws an error like `Failed to connect to server`. There is no detailed exception, but it says `disconnected` under that sentence.

- I'm sure both me and the host are on the same network, because I tried
  to connect the PCs directly, ***PC -->RJ45--> PC***. But the thing is that it shows every detail on the server page like how many players are online, the world name, and the latency, which is just 1 ms through direct connection.
- Both of us allowed `javaw.exe` to go through the Windows firewall.
- We tried using many different Minecraft versions, still the same.
- We can play on online servers without any problem.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: @Joachim thanks I for the edit. I tried to mean Minecraft versions but I've forgot to type it. Thanks for the edits anyway

Comment: Why am I getting downvotes? this is an important problem to me...

Comment: Can you ping from one computer to the other?

Comment: @user253751use yes and it's soo fast

Comment: Do both computers have internet access? If not, is the server in offline mode?

Comment: @user253751 yes it is on the offline mode

Answer (score -2):

You can simply reset the router, then retry connecting. If this is not the case, I would recommend you to visit this [WEBSITE](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/minecraft-lan-not-working.html).

Comment: nope, all of those didn't work